# IBM MFP8 Oracle Binary Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MFP 8, Javascript SQL Adapter, in my POM.xml
I have added the dependency for Oracle library and build is successful, working fine..

But In Code review, Getting a critical error as

**Update this scope and remove the "systemPath"**

system
${basedir}/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar

How to resolve the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a maven error which you are getting as you have added the library directly as a dependency.

You can solve this by adding the Oracle library to your local maven repository and add it as maven dependency in POM file. Alternatively (better option) specify the proper repository (if one exists) so it can be automatically downloaded by maven.